# jenkins 2x multibranch pipeline Behaviors

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, multibranch-pipeline

Can someone please explain different behaviors option available as a part of Jenkins 2x Multibranch Pipeline and what is the right strategy to choose in an enterprise environment.

I see three options:

- Discover branches
- Discover pull requests from origin
- Discover pull requests from forks

and they have 3 options too. Can someone please point me to the best practices and what right options to pick up?

Comment: What is your usecase?